# Regex for string with commas and quotes

Tags: java, regex

I have a similar string

```
'a,b,c,"0,0,0,1",d,"0,0,0,2","0,0,0,3"'
```

and i need to split it by using regex, and it is not working properly if just to use comma `","` character

It results with `'a', 'b', 'c', '"0', '0', '1"', 'd'` and so on...
I need somehow specify that regex should be `','` but not `'",'` or `'","'`

Comment: What type of languages you are using?

Comment: String.split method in java

Comment: this expression seem to work in my case ,(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)